# Sitecore: Customize treelistform

Tags: treeview, sitecore, sitecore6, treelist

I want to add extra control (multilist ) into the Treelist form. How can I do it? 
I already have a Custom treelist and tried to modified OnLoad method in the custom treelist by replacing TreeviewEx to MultilistEx. (The custom tree code was copied directly using .NET reflactor)

The error shown: 
[Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: current 
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. 
Parameter name: current] 
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.MultilistEx.GetItems(Item current) +104 
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.MultilistEx.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output) +146]

I use Reflactor to check the Sitecore.Kernel.dll, and I suspect that the Item current was not initially set to any value.

*Instead of adding MultilistEx into the TreeList Form, can I modify the tree to look alike multilist?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean you are trying to add a multilist into the Treelist control? What exactly are you trying to use this new control for?

Answer (score 0):

The error is a simple missing argument, check the posted form names/values to see if there's a mismatch.